# Can microdialysis be made in Drosophila melanogaster?

Tags: neuroscience, methodology

Microdialysis is a common method to study the effects of drugs on specific mamal brains zones (mostly in rats), in order to study the it's interaction with the function of those specific areas that controls or mediates in complex behavior.

There are invertebrates who are well known for providing genetic tools to study both behaviour and pharmacology of drugs, like c. elegans and Drosophila melanogaster. The last one has been also used for attention, learning and hyperactivity study, as a model for ADHD.

While I found a couple of studies which uses microdialysis on insect brains, I couldn't reach anyone for microdialysis in Drosophila. Is it possible to do microdialysis in Drosophila? Otherwise, there are alternatives to oral administration of drugs in insects like Drosophila?

--
Edit: Thanks for your insights, I have a computer science background and its hard to me to try to talk with property about these things completely out of my comfort zone. 
Also, I specified the original target, Drosophila Melanogaster, since there are bigger parients like Hawaian D. heteroneura and D. cyrtoloma. where current probes could be used """without too much trouble"""

Comment: @NickStauner I disagree, this is a common method in neuroscience.

Comment: (this page reads like an advertisement, but it is a good summary - http://www.psychogenics.com/microdialysis.html)

Comment: Thank you Chuck,

I've found microdialysis probes with a membrane  diameter of 240um , while the head of Drosophila must be around 200-300um , but I was wondering if the lack of microdialysis studies in Drosophila is just due to this technical constraint.

Comment: See the relevant meta-question: [Are questions about neurobiology on or off topic?](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/23/4086) This debate is somewhat unresolved. We need your thoughts and votes!

Comment: I would assume, regardless of the acceptability of the question on this board, chances for a good answer are probably a lot more likely over at Biology.

Comment: @NickStauner I can certainly appreciate your arguments.  I think in this instance there's not that degree of ambiguity between the method's use in different disciplines, but I do concede to your point (and jona's) that it might get a different set of eyes on Bio.SE.

Comment: Thanks @NickStauner, jona and Chuck, I made this question in Bio.SE (http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/20840/8992) and reddit, where I got a few hints.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for being up-front about cross-posting. I've withdrawn my close vote and upvoted (on Bio too; you still have a permanent downvote from a VLQ flag here – see [this MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111589/246931) for context / discussion on that – but it didn't cost you any reputation, so it's nothing to worry about). Seems you've written both versions differently to suit the respective topics, which is really all the more I could've asked for. Might as well leave both open and see who has what to say. Good luck!